# Character spacing of font on Putty

Tags: putty

Is there a way to change character spacing of a fixed width font for Putty. I did not find any option for this.

Answer (score 1):

Character spacing is an attribute of the font itself. If you want different spacing, you'll have to use a different font.

Comment: That is not entirely true. I use rxvt as well and can specify character spacing using letterSpacing property to any font. I am looking for possibly a similar option in Putty, if it exists.